Return specific type of Collection depending on the type of argument
I'm trying to write a mapper that can take in a Collection<A> and return a Collection<B>. That part is easy, but I'm trying to make it so that the returned Collection is of the same type as the input one.
So calling aToB(Set.of(new A())) would return a Set<B>, for example. And more importantly, I want the compiler to be aware of it.
I tried using generics, but it seems it's not really possible due to the fact I can't parameterize a generic. The following doesn't work:
public <C extends Collection> C<B> aToB(C<A> coll) {}

Stuff like the following loses the fact that the collections must be the same type, and the compiler isn't happy either way:
public <C extends Collection<A>, D extends Collection<B>> D aToB(C coll) {}

I know it's not a practical case and that I should simply write multiple methods, which I did, but I'm curious about whether it is possible or not.
As a side question, I'm also interested in why the following code doesn't compile either, saying there I provide List when C is required.
public <C extends Collection<String>> C aaa() {
    List<String> a = List.of("AAA");
    return a;
}

Thanks

Immutable collection types exist, and collections with all sorts of restrictions on what you can do with them. Handling all of them generically is not realistic at all. You can probably cater for the most common mutable SequencedCollection types as well as Collections types that implement all optional mutating methods, htough. One idea is to clone your Collection<A>, cast the clone to Collection<B> and replace each element. It will give you the same runtime type, which will also imply the same compile-time type, though the caller may need a cast.


I know it's not a practical case and that I should simply write multiple methods, which I did, but I'm curious about whether it is possible or not.

It is not.  The closest thing is requiring the user to pass in a Supplier<Collection<B>>, which is not too bad, e.g. users can pass ArrayList::new.

As a side question, I'm also interested in why the following code doesn't compile either, saying there I provide List when C is required.

class Foo {
  // let's suppose this compiled
  public <C extends Collection<String>> C aaa() {
    List<String> a = List.of("AAA");
    return a;
  }

  // then what do you think happens here?  this is valid Java
  public void bbb() {
    HashSet<String> set = Foo.<HashSet<String>>aaa();
  }
}

C is specified by the caller.  If you want to promise the user that you are going to return some subtype of Collection<String>, but not specify what it is, then the appropriate method type is
public Collection<String> aaa() { ... }


Passing a supplier is clever, I didn't think of that. It may in fact be a good idea for my use case, since it's more flexible, and allows the caller to dictate the type of the returned collection disregarding the input collection's type, even mapping a Set to a List if need be.

It is impossible in Java.
You need separate methods for each collection type.
PS: You can try Scala if you want it to work. 
PPS: Your side question doesn't work because there are other classes implementing Collection.

Thanks. I think I get it thanks to your PPS.
